# Opencart и список основных категорий сайта

Tags: база-данных, opencart

Подскажите, как вытащить список пунктов категорий(меню) из базы данных минуя все контролёры и прочие модули? Как не пытался найти таблицу и ключи, но так и не нашёл путей ведущих к выводу данных.

В шаблоне просто откуда-то возникает $categories, который в себе всё содержит. Где он определяется не могу найти.

А нужно вытащить генерацию меню в отдельный файл, который не подключен к основной системе opencart`a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В шаблоне они появляются из контроллера, а вот данные в нем берутся из модели `catalog/model/catalog/category.php`

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$data['categories'] = array();
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
```

Ну а в модели:

```
public function getCategories($parent_id = 0) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) WHERE c.parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'  AND c.status = '1' ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)");
        return $query->rows;
    }
```